# PHP suhosin view dropped variables?

Tags: php

suhosin enabled.
suhosin dropping request/get variables.

The log just tells me everything except the original value of the dropped variable.

```
ALERT - dropped 1 request variables - (1 in GET, 0 in POST, 0 in COOKIE) 
(attacker 'xx.x.xx.x.x', file '/html/index.html')
ALERT - configured GET variable value length limit exceeded -
dropped variable 'url' (attacker 'x.x.x.x', file '/html/index.html')
```

**How can I view the original value of the dropped variable?**

Answer (score 1):

I was able to check the original URL and parameters by grep'ing the Apache access.log.